# Using $(outdir) in VSO after the build

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Using visualstudio.com as hosted TFS:

How do you access the $(outdir) of the build in batch file run after the build is completed?  Setting up a build agent and repository for someone else, and the code is not mine so I don't want to have to change the build definition, only access the output folder as specified in the code for a post-build batch file.

See the image link below.  The "Visual Studio Build" step uses different $(outdir) construction based on the build platform and configuration.

I need to be able to access the folder in the Batch Script step without modifying the build.

Build Steps Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Specify the outdir in MSBuild argument could achieve the things you want more easily.

Since you don't want to change the build definition, you can use "BuildConfiguration" and "BuildPlatform" variables when the output path is based on the build platform and configuration.

In your case, the output path should like following:

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Logbinder$(ProductAbbrev)/Resources/Mtg.Logbinder.$(ProductAbbrev)/bin/$(BuildPlatform)/$(BuildConfiguration)
```